# Why does the back and forth method fail to prove that, for each cardinality, any dense linear order without endpoints is unique up to isomorphism?

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, model-theory, cardinals, ordinals

First of all I must say I'm not not very knowledgeable about set theory beyond the very basics, so please bear with me if I've made some obvious mistakes in my reasoninig.

I've looked at and understood the argument for countably infinite sets. Using the formulation in [the wikipedia article on the back and forth method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-and-forth_method) as basis I feel like one should be able to generalise this to any cardinality, assuming the axiom of choice. I would formulate it like this:

Given two densely ordered sets without endpoints $(A, <_A)$ and $(B, <_B)$ of the same (infinite) cardinality $\kappa$, let $\{a_\beta\}_{\beta<\kappa}$ and $\{b_\beta\}_{\beta<\kappa}$ be enumerations of $A$ and $B$ (without repetitions). Then we construct an isomorphism between them as follows:

1. Let $\beta$ be the smallest index such that no $a_\beta$ has been paired with any $b_\gamma$. Choose an unpaired $b_\gamma$ such that if $a_\delta<a_\beta<a_\eta$, with $a_\delta$ already been paired with $b_\delta$ and $a_\eta$ already been paired with $b_\eta$, we have $b_\delta<b_\gamma<b_\eta$. This we can do because the ordering is dense. Otherwise, choose an unpaired $b_\gamma$ to be either larger or smaller than all previous choices, based on whether $a_\beta$ was larger or smaller than each previously chosen element of $A$. This we can do because the ordering has no endpoints.
2. Analogously for an element of $B$.
3. Go to step 1.

We repeat these steps for each ordinal less than $\kappa$. Where does this fail to define an isomorphism as it does for the countable case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you have only matched a finite number of elements $a_0,\ldots , a_n,$ it is clear that you can choose an $a_{n+1}$ between any two of the $a_i$ (or above or below all of them). That's not so clear when the the number of elements you have matched is infinite. What's worse, you need to choose your next $a$ to satisfy an infinite set of betweenness conditions. It's not nearly clear as you make it out to be that this can be done.

Comment: Note that this points the way to a result which *does* hold - namely, any two linear orders $A,B$ of size $\kappa$ without endpoints which are "$<\kappa$-dense" are isomorphic. It's just that once $\kappa$ is uncountable, this condition is stronger than mere density.

Comment: Is the problem with infinity here that you might have exhausted all options after an infinite number of steps? If so, isn't this just a matter of which choices you made? But by using the axiom of choice, can you not guarantee there is a sequence of choices that avoids this?

Comment: Oh I think I see an issue now, taking into account the comment by @NoahSchweber. Density doesn't mean there will be $\kappa$ elements between each pair of elements. So I see that this leads to the formulation above to not be enough.

Comment: @Tobias You may want to puzzle over a counterexample to see what goes wrong when you try to shoe-horn an isomorphism in when there isn't one... e.g. $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R\setminus \{0\}.$ (And e.g. how is that different from $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb Q\setminus\{0\},$ which *are* isomorphic.)